# React Native Collapsible springy Header with PanResponder

Tags: react-native

There are many examples available from great developers around the world for collapsible header which work based on the scroll value of scrollView. But I'm trying to implement the same by using PanResponder.

Here is what I'm trying to achieve [imgur link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0JnP.jpg)

in terms of React Native if I explain the screen components we see in the image is a header at the top and a scrollView thereafter (lets skip the directory breadcrumbs)

initially when the screen renders the header stays collapsed, if we slide down the screen the header expands with a springy animation similarly when sliding up the header gets back to initial collapsed state with animation. During the header collapse / expansion the scrollView scroll stays lock until the header animation is complete i.e we have to track gesture via PanResponder.
If we slide up the header to any position that is less than 50% of the header then the header springs back & expands, similarly reverse happens when sliding down from a collapsed condition.

In last few days I went up to the expand & collapse part but can't figure out the springy effect for the header animation now my back is against the wall, any help will be much appreciated

Here is the code

```js
class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            pan: new Animated.ValueXY(),
            items: [1,2,3,4,5]
        };

        this.animY = new Animated.Value(0);
        this.lastY = 0;

        this._panResponder = PanResponder.create({
            onStartShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => true,
            onStartShouldSetPanResponderCapture: (evt, gestureState) => true,
            onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => true,
            onMoveShouldSetPanResponderCapture: (evt, gestureState) => true,

            onPanResponderGrant: (evt, gestureState) => {
            },
            onPanResponderMove: (evt, gestureState) => {
                let { dy } = gestureState;
                this.animY.setValue(this.lastY + dy);
              },
            onPanResponderTerminationRequest: (evt, gestureState) => true,
            onPanResponderRelease: (evt, gestureState) => {
                let { dy } = gestureState;
                this.lastY += dy;
            },
        });
    }

    handleScroll = () => {
        console.log('scroll init');
    }

    render() {
        this.state.pan.addListener((value) => {
            console.log('animY', this.animY);
        });

        const AnimateHeaderHeight = Animated.diffClamp(this.animY, -200, 0).interpolate(
        {
            inputRange: [ -200, 0 ],
            outputRange: [ 50, 200 ],
            extrapolate: 'clamp'
        });

        return (
            <View style={{flex: 1}}>
                <Animated.View style={[{backgroundColor: '#4287f5', height: AnimateHeaderHeight}]}>
                    <Text>Sample</Text>
                </Animated.View>
                <ScrollView style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#e6efff'}}
                    onScroll={this.handleScroll}
                    {...this._panResponder.panHandlers}
                    scrollEnabled={false}
                >
                    {this.state.items.map((item, index) => {
                        return (
                            <View style={styles.item} key={index}>
                                <Text>Sample</Text>
                            </View>
                        )
                    })} 
                </ScrollView>
            </View>
        )
    }
};
```

here is the output of my above code [image: result till now]